# mysql_connection.h file not found

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake

I am attempting to utilise the connector/c++ for MySQL in order to connect use mysql commands in c++
When attempting to build I get the fatal error

```
fatal error: mysql_connection.h: No such file or directory
```

Thanks,

CMAKE

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Music_Player)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(Music_Player main.cpp)

set(BOOST_ROOT "boost_1_77_0")

find_package(Boost)
if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif()

set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/cppconn)
link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib)
target_link_libraries(Music_Player curl mysqlcppconn)
target_compile_features(Music_Player PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"



int main() {
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("http:/localhost:8889", "root", "root");

    delete con;
}
```

Comment: `set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0)` I believe you need to quote that path.

Comment: @drescherjm I have done this it does not appear to fix it

Comment: You will have to look at the Makefile or your IDE to see what is wrong with the include path.